# How to use Android Studio Activities

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-activity

I'm new to Kotlin and Android studio, I previously completed a project of mine with KivyMD, I want to replicate the project with `Kotlin` using Android studio, the project has 56 screens, I've learnt that activities represents screen in Android Studio, which means I'll have to create 55 more activities in additional to `MainActivity`, thinking that might be a bit much I googled if they is a limit to number of activities I can create I found it's 10..

So how do I put the contents of other screens? or Could I just go ahead and create all 56 activities??

Thanks to you for your help in advance..

Comment: There's no limit to the number of activities you can include

Comment: Anyway, it's generally recommended to use a single Activity and use Fragments in that Activity to represent the different screens. Android now has a WYSIWYG editor for mapping out the screens of your app. You can read about the Navigation Component in the documentation if you're interested.  56 seems like an unusually high number of Activities or Fragments for a starter project or to practice with. You might consider a design where the same Fragment class can represent multiple different screens by giving it different parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack) is a bunch of libraries created to ease app development and help people follow best practices, and [the official recommendation](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/use-android-jetpack-to-accelerate-your.html?m=1) is a single-Activity app:

> **Navigation**
>
> While activities are the system provided entry points into your app's UI, their inflexibility when it comes to sharing data between each other and transitions has made them a less than ideal architecture for constructing your in-app navigation. Today we are introducing the Navigation component as a framework for structuring your in-app UI, **with a focus on making a single-Activity app the preferred architecture**.

By using the Navigation component, your `Activity` is basically a container for `Fragment`s, which act as your "screens". Navigation handles a lot of the boilerplate for swapping them in and out and maintaining history, and you focus more on connecting them together in a *navigation graph*.

It's a lot to learn at first, but it's definitely worth it, and if you're going to be messing with 56 destinations then you'll probably end up saving a lot of time letting it handle the bulk of the work! [Here's a codelab tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation#0) you can do to get up to speed with it, and [here's the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) which starts with the basics and gets to some of the more complex uses

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, and you are definitely right it's a lot to learn..

Comment: @Edwin To be fair, if you're new to the whole Fragments thing in general, *that's* a lot to learn (and so is doing everything with Activities and getting them all to talk to each other). You've gotta learn something, may as well be the modern way that's there to make things easier!